# Python - Can't create instances from a list or random instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a small text RPG to help me learn the Python language, and I am trying to create multiple instances of a class from a list of names.

I have a class of enemies (Named: Enemy) and would like to create between 1 and 3 "goblin" enemies at at time.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, health):
        self.health = health
```

How I have approached the problem so far is to use a for loop to run through letters 'a', 'b', and 'c' and append a list of enemies.

```
for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
    enemylist.append('goblin' + (i))
```

This gives me a list of three goblins:

```
['goblina', 'goblinb', 'goblinc']
```

Now I would like to take each newly appended "goblin" in the list and create an instance of the enemy class using that goblin's name (Example: "goblina = enemy(10)"... "goblinb = enemy(10)...)

But when I try to create an instance using any number of ways including the following (which is probably the absolutely wrong way to):

```
for i in range (1, 3):
    enemylist[i] = enemy(10)
```

All that I get is a single instance named `enemylist[i]`.

Can someone please help me. Like I said, I am new to the language so please be gentle with the explanation but I am a fast learner and willing to read and research.

I spent the better part of 2 days (on and off) trying to get to the bottom of this and could not find a solution that worked.

Comment: How are you getting the "name" of the instance?

Comment: Perhaps you're not looking for a list, but rather a keyed dictionary: [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html). It's an associative array in other languages.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Getting the name of the instance is also part of the problem as written in a reply to Jonathon below. I would like the name of the instance to be the value of the for loop (EG: goblina).

Comment: How does that make more sense than having a sequence of instances, whose length you can actually get instead of having to guess?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, Thank you for the time to reply. Like I said, I am new to Python. Could you give me an example of what you are discussing so I can better understand what you mean?

Comment: Both/either of the given answers is what I'm talking about.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, neither of the answers create a series if instances with the name(s) that are evaluated within the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think adding a **name** to the class is good, but creating a dict with a key that's equal to the same name, but also storing the name and health as a dict value seems a bit redundant (as shown in answer above).

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

This will give you a **name** to access. You can still store each instance of the enemy class in a list, using list comprehension if you like (or any other list creation):

```
for i in enemylist:
    i = Enemy(i, 10)
    enemies.append(i)
```

Now you have a list enemies, consisting of three instantiated objects of the class Enemy, that have a name that can be accessed. For instance

```
goblina.__name__
```

will return goblina and

```
isintance(goblina, Enemy)
```

will return True.

Comment: Thank you mcbrandt13 for the help but I still need to create a instance name from a known list of names. That way I can check and see if (Example: "goblina') exists in the enemies class.

Comment: mcbrandt, Thank you for writing that out. when I call a function of the enemy class (Exmaple: goblina.printing() ) I still get an error that says goblina is not defined. But when I call i.printing() it works fine so the for loop isn't passing the name correctly from what I can see and understand.  Any thoughts?

Comment: By "goblina.printing()" do you mean "print(goblina)"? Anyway, the instances you are creating in the for loop only exist within that for loop (and then in the list they are appended to). If you try and do print(goblina) outside of the for loop it is created in, outside being the global namespace, it won't be recognized (except for the last item in enemylist that was iterated over by the for loop, which is probably goblinc). If you need to keep those instance names in the global namespace, I would instantiate them outside of a for loop.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I now understand why the instance does not work when not called or put to work inside the for loop or inside a function of its own. Right now, I have an "Attack" function inside the character class of the text rpg I am writing. I know its hard to say without seeing it and if you would like I will paste all of the code, but on your opinion, would it be best to have attack be a function outside of all classes that creates goblin instances (enemies) and then they will be garbage collected once the function is completed?

Comment: I think an attack function could stay as a function of the character class. You just want to make sure it's set up to accept some object of the Enemy class as an argument, whether that's a standalone global Enemy object, or one Enemy object within a global list of enemy objects that you feed to attack() by a for loop. If you have a character class object of "Warrior", you'd do Warrior.attack(goblina), and have the attack function subtract some random amount from  goblina's health. If you like, you can provide more of the code to me via email to go over.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I assume that I will have more questions along the way but I deeply appreciate the offer. If you are still up to the task as I continue to complete the storytelling rpg, I will send you the code as it nears its completion and maybe your trained eye could help me make it more memory and programmer friendly.  Thank you again! This was my first post on StackOverflow and your attention to detail and help made it an enjoyable experience. I will come back and vote you up once I get enough points. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help, and would be happy to take a look and offer what advice I can at whatever stage.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would make more sense to keep the enemy's name as a member of the `Enemy` class as well:

```
import random

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health

def create_enemies():
    enemies = []
    for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        name = 'goblin'+i
        health =  random.randint(10,20)
        enemies.append(Enemy(name, health))
```

It's hard to make a suggestion without knowing how you're going to *use* the enemies.  If you want to be able to look an enemy up by name, a dictionary would be a better data structure in which to store them:

```
def create_enemies():
    enemies = {}                   # Initialize empty dict
    for i in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
        name = 'goblin'+i
        health =  random.randint(10,20)
        enemies[name] = Enemy(name, health)
    return enemies

def main()
    enemies = create_enemies()

    ga = enemies['goblina']
```

Comment: Jonathon, thank you for taking the time to help. How will each instance of the Enemy class be named? Since the for loop create an enemy name (EG: goblina), I tried to create a print function within the Enemy class and call it using goblina.print() but received an error.  How can I know the name of the instance and how to call it for other functions?

To answer your other question on how the enemies will be used... I am using isinstance to see if an enemy exists within a class and if he does exist with positive health, the player can attack him.